# Проблема rem и минимального размера шрифта в браузере

Tags: html, css

Есть сверстанный сайт на `rem` единицах измерения.

В браузерах где установлен минимальный размер шрифта ***к примеру `10px`*** сайт ломается.

Пробую установить свойство `-webkit-text-size-adjust:none:` не помогает.

Можно как-нибудь обойти этот минимальны размер?

Comment: А то, что ты используешь`rem` , а `body` -  задал `font-size`???   `rem` - это `ROOT-em`

Comment: font-size я задал html, вернее он высчитывается js, к примеру если экран 1920 то html:font-size 1px, а если экран на 20% меньше то html:font-size 0.8px

Comment: @MaratCh, а зачем вы это делаете?

Comment: @E_K чтоб весь сайт пропорционально уменьшался, то есть на любых экранах выглядел хорошо, как в дизайне